# CSS: Div jumps down

Tags: html, css

I got a major issue with the last overlapping div jumping down below the one before when narrowing down the web browser and thereby aligning them to the right. I don't know how to solve it. I've tried Google etc. What's happening and why? And how do I solve this?

```
<div id="why-use-fastq-wrapper">
  <div id="why-use-fastq">
    <h3>WHY SHOULD WE USE FASTQ?</h3>
    <div id="why-use-fastq-img">
      <img src="images/bg2.png">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="step-teaser2">
<div class="step-container2">
  <div class="left2"> 
        <div class="img2">
      <img src="images/sustainable.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-title2">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="right2">
       <div class="img2">
    <img src="images/easy.png" alt="" />
  </div>
        <div class="step-title2">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="step-container2">
  <div class="left2"> 
      <div class="img2">
      <img src="images/plan.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-title2">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="right2">
        <div class="img2">
        <img src="images/stress.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-title2">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
        <p>TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


#why-use-fastq-wrapper h3{
  font-family: gill sans;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#why-use-fastq-wrapper{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
  #why-use-fastq{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
    #why-use-fastq-img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
    #why-use-fastq-img img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
.step-teaser2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.step-container2 {
  margin: 40px auto;

  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;

  height: 225px;  /* same as left/right */

  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.step-container2 .step-title2 {
  font-family: gill sans;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.step-container2 p {
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: justify;
}

.img2{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.left2 {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
}

.left2 img {
  text-align: center;
  width:100px;
}

.right2 {
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
}

.right2 img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}


@media(max-width: 640px) {

    .step-container2 {
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    .step-container2 img {
      display: none;
    }

    .left2 {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .right2 {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem in more details. I don't see any problem with your code, see the link http://jsfiddle.net/086p6jtz/

Comment: The last dive is staying at the last position itself: http://jsfiddle.net/6g887d4v/3/ What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Cannot see the problem either. Unless you mean the overlapping divs once you narrow down the window?

Comment: Exactly, it's when i narrow down that the problem arises and I really don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **.step-container2**'s height to "auto" at your 640px breakpoint;

```
@media(max-width: 640px) {    
    .step-container2 {
       height:auto;  // add this
       margin: 0 auto; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it if you float your 'p' or the 'div' element to the left. This way it do not overlap.